# Issue with Map<Range,List> de/serialization with Object Mapper

Tags: java, range, guava, jackson-databind

In the following method when trying to use deserialized Map created from object mapper, upon reading the key value JVM is throwing an error.

```
public void someMethod() {

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1234", "12314");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date1 = dateFormat.parse("2021-11-25 00:00:00");
        Date date2 = dateFormat.parse("2021-11-26 00:00:00");
        Range<Instant> range = Range.closed(date1.toInstant(), date2.toInstant());
        
        // Google range
        Map<Range<Instant>, List<String>> map = ImmutableMap.of(
            rangeA, listA,
        );
        
        // Jackson object mapper
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final String serializedMap = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
        // both de/serialized object are created as expected.
        Map<Range<Instant>, List<String>> deserializedMap = mapper.readValue(serializedMap, Map.class);
        // 
        System.out.println(serializedMap);
        // {"[2021-11-25T08:00:00Z..2021-11-26T08:00:00Z]":["1234","12314"],"[2021-11-25T20:00:00Z..2021-11-26T20:00:00Z]":["9999","1010","1234"]}
        System.out.println(deserializedMap);
       // {[2021-11-25T08:00:00Z..2021-11-26T08:00:00Z]=[1234, 12314], [2021-11-25T20:00:00Z..2021-11-26T20:00:00Z]=[9999, 1010, 1234]}

        // This line is throwing error
        deserializedMap.entrySet().stream().map(rangeListEntry -> rangeListEntry.getKey()).forEach(System.out::println); 

}
```

Error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.google.common.collect.Range`

Couple things I have tried but didn't work:

```
        // for Java 8 related feature 
        mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module()); 
        // https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
       // mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
       // for collections.
        mapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());
```

Am I doing anything wrong here or is this a bug ?

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try registering `GuavaModule`, found in the `jackson-datatype-guava` artifact.

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());
```

Comment: Tried that but getting same error.